# What's the policy in regard to Kabbalah questions?

Tags: discussion, policy

There are halachik and cultural norms about if Kabbalah can be learnt, and discussed in public. It's part of Judaism but it is an area that needs to be handled delicately.  What is the policy here?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1720/2

Answer (score 9):

The [FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> Please respect that in the Jewish tradition certain questions, especially certain questions relating to sexuality, are discussed only in private. Such questions will be closed or deleted at the discretion of the moderators or community.

That would seem to apply hereto. You can vote/flag to close a question if you think it's about material that in Judaism is only discussed in private. If enough people agree with you, the question will be closed.

I personally haven't found this to be a big issue around here. Most Kabbalistic material posted goes over my head anyway and thus probably also over every single random internet user who isn't a trained Kabbalist. The content is visible in public but it's not available to the public.