# Question deleted without private feedback - no way to contact the moderators

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I asked a [legitimate question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130871/40-days-before-formation-how-does-this-apply-to-lgbtq-people) about a gemara and how it relates to people who are born LGBTQ. The question was closed without an answer, and without a private message.

Is there any way to contact the moderators and ask them to clarify? Calling a question that references LGBTQ people as "relating to sexuality/immodest" is frankly homophobic. It is not a private question, nor a sexual one, and wild discretion to delete questions we don't like can be harmful in a number of ways.

Comment: As noted elsewhere https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4634/759 the policy  utilized here is not only about questions related to sexuality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post was closed by votes of five community members not by a moderator.

For information on what to do if you believe your post was closed incorrectly, please see: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions

---

Regarding this closure in particular, I don't see how the closure reason, which is generally for sexually-explicit material, applies to this post. There is nothing explicit in it at all.