# What advanced existing features of SE/MY would a more experienced user want to know?

Tags: discussion

Two months after I joined MY, I wrote a [beginner's guide](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Some have found it useful and have been pointing new users to it in their welcome message.

Two and a half years later I have learned a few more tricks, but [recently realized](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4722/how-can-we-encourage-posters-to-fix-their-questions/4723?noredirect=1#comment14718_4723) there were more I still didn't know.

So I thought of a small list of links to such advanced features which might be useful for more experienced users. I invite you to expand the answer below or, even better, add yours.

Answer (score 9):

- [HTML tags allowed in messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) (e.g., br for line breaks, sup for smaller characters)
- [Advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) (e.g., is:question to see only questions)
- [Hidden features of StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange) (e.g., [this handy way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286545/312691) to resize pictures)
- ["Magic links" in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/312691) (I particularly like [edit] -- thanks to Monica Cellio and DoubleAA)
- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)
- [MY glossary](/q/581) to link words to that require definitions
- [Mi Yodeya Referencer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1758/472) (userscript) to generate links to common sources
- Markdown editing:

  - Using the buttons at the top of post-editing boxes.
  - Using the "?" button on the top-right to get instructions for using the buttons.
  - Full [Markdown Help page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help)
- List of handy websites for linking directly to sources: [Sefaria](http://sefaria.org), [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/109864/jewish/Classic-Texts.htm), [HebrewBooks Beta](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org), [AlHatorah](http://alhatorah.org/), [Mechon Mamre](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/),  [Wikisource](//he.wikisource.org).
- [SEDE Tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)

Comment: I saw parts of this a few times. That means that I didn't know that most of this existed. And, if it weren't for my occasionally viewing the sidebar, I wouldn't have noticed this now. My point, here, is that "Meta" really isn't that prominent for most users, and it's not intuitive. The editor toolbar **is** but it's only for questions, not comments. Ideally, a better toolbar would do most of the job. But, I agree, that it would probably clutter the page, too. I'm not sure if there **is** a way to create a good balance.